# CORS policy blocking my post request after disabling it globally in my Spring Boot Application

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot Security with JWT and Angular 7 for frontend getting this error when trying to register a user:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/users/register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my Angular code getting called:

```
 register(username, firstName, lastName, email, password) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:8080/users/register`,
    {
      username,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password
    });
  }
```

This is my Spring Boot **WebConfiguration** Class:

```
    @Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

This is my **WebSecurity** class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

I am a begginer so please tell me if I am missing anything.

Comment: Tried a lot of solutions for this particular problem on stack-overflow and  none worked, only than I decided to post.

Comment: You didn't use the Spring way for CORS. See the other question and the [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cors).

Comment: @VictorV The code you posted within your question doesn't define the `CorsConfigurationSource` bean as mentioned in the possible duplicate. So right now, I agree with @dur that this is a duplicate, and I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pre-flight request (RequestMethod.OPTIONS) is made by some browsers as a safety measure to ensure that the request being done is trusted by the server. Meaning the server understands that the method, origin and headers being sent on the request are safe to act upon. 
*WebConfig for CORS*

You can create one WebConfig Class for CORS Origin Configuration

*WebConfig.java*

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "USERID");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "ROLE");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
      System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
      if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
          try {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("Pre-flight");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
          "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                  "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      }

    }

}
```

---

[CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html)

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors().and()
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: @dur the other solution is better if it works ? The solution you linked too when you marked my question as duplicate.

Comment: Hello @VictorV we have another approach as given above, both are working fine, I have attached a sample from docs